# Translate/scale axes on splot (heat map) of matrix in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to load a 60x150 matrix from a data file to create a heat map. I would like for these data points to span the range [-30,29] on the y axis, and [0:1490] on the x-axis. How can I scale/translate the tics on each axis to meet up with my data points? I need to translate on the y-axis and scale on the x-axis.

I'm using the following commands in `gnuplot`:

```
set datafile separator ","
set view map
set size 0.9,0.9
set palette gray
set xtics 0,20,1500
set ytics -30,5,30
splot "test.dat" matrix with image
```

And I get the following output:
[image: My Gnuplot output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to rescale x and y coordinates with `using`. `stats` will give you the size of the matrix in file.

```
ym=-30
yM=29
xm=0
xM=1490
stats "test.dat" matrix
itox(i)=xm+(xM-xm)*i/STATS_size_x
jtoy(j)=ym+(yM-ym)*j/STATS_size_y
splot "test.dat" matrix using (itox(column(1)):(jtoy(column(2)):3 with image
```